# Evaluating $\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-u} e^{-v} e^{i \alpha (\sin(\omega u + \phi) - \sin(\omega v + \phi))} du\ dv\ d\phi $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I recently came across the following definite integral while working on a model involving the overlap of quantum-mechanical photon wavefunctions under some periodic modulation:
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-u} \mathrm{e}^{-v} \mathrm{e}^{i \alpha (\sin(\omega u + \phi) - \sin(\omega v + \phi))} \mathrm{d}u\  \mathrm{d}v\ \mathrm{d}\phi, $$
where $\alpha > 0$, $\omega > 0$.

A typical parameter regime I would be interested in for any approximate solutions would be $\omega \approx 2.5$, $\alpha \in [0, 3]$ (and in particular, $\alpha \ll 1$).

The result is real, and evaluated numerically across $\alpha \in [0, 10]$, looks roughly like a smeared-out Bessel function of the first kind, as you might expect from the sine in the exponent. Is there some clever contour integration trick for simplifying this? I didn't find anything using Mathematica/… (and a quick manual check, but Bessel functions, etc. were never my strength).

Comment: I’m guessing you mean $d\phi\,du\,dv$, *i.e.* it is the $\phi$ integral that runs from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: $\phi$ runs from 0 to 2π, yes, but the order in the question should be just that, and is the only convention I'm familiar with (natural nesting, just imagine some parantheses).

Comment: The inner double integral factors as: $$\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u+i\alpha\sin(\omega u+\phi)}\,du\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-v-i\alpha\sin(\omega v+\phi)}\,dv\right)$$ and the product is of complex conjugates,  so you should get a positive real.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The $du\,dv\,d\phi$ is the correct order - the outer $dx$ corresponds to the outer integral.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess we learn in different ways…

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah yes, of course (have been staring at this for too long), thanks; fixed in the question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Where did you learn? I makes no sense to order them the way you want.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Specifically, we want: $$\int_a^b \int_c^d f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_a^b\left(\int_c^d f(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx.$$ Your order would make this equality more complicated.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews To be clear, I learned the preferable notation would be $\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{\infty} du f(\phi, u) $ or equivalently $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} d\phi du f(\phi,u) $ so first the integral goes with first the differential element *etc*.  Almost same as you have except you have the differential element at the back.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero You're using notation that physicists like to use, but mathematicians don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a trigonometric identity, we can rewrite the integral as
$$ I (\alpha,\omega) = \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-(u+v)} \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathrm{i} \alpha \sin (\omega (u-v)/2) \cos(\phi + \omega (u+v)/2)} \, \mathrm{d} \phi \, \mathrm{d} u \, \mathrm{d} v \, . $$
The shift in the cosine can be ignored as the integration is over a whole period anyway, so the [integral representation of the Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel%27s_integrals) yields
$$ I(\alpha,\omega) = 2 \pi \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-(u+v)} \operatorname{J}_0 \left[2 \alpha \sin \left(\frac{\omega(u-v)}{2}\right)\right] \, \mathrm{d} u \, \mathrm{d} v \, . $$
Now we change variables to $x = u - v$ and $y = u + v$. The Jacobian is $1/2$ and the new integration region is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon y > \lvert x \rvert\}$. Just like the integrand, it is symmetric in $x$, so we can integrate over the part with $x>0$ twice to find
\begin{align}
I (\alpha, \omega) &= 2 \cdot 2 \pi \cdot \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_x^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-y} \operatorname{J}_0 \left[2 \alpha \sin \left(\frac{\omega x}{2}\right)\right] \, \mathrm{d} y \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&= 2 \pi \int \limits_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x} \operatorname{J}_0 \left[2 \alpha \sin \left(\frac{\omega x}{2}\right)\right] \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
\end{align}
While a closed-form expression for the remaining integral seems unlikely, it can easily be approximated. The [series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1) of $\operatorname{J}_0$ leads to
$$ I(\alpha,\omega) = 2\pi \left[1 - \frac{\omega^2 \alpha^2}{2(1+\omega^2)} + \mathcal{O} \left(\alpha^4\right)\right] $$
for example and higher-order terms are readily computed.

Comment: Wow, that was quick – and including helpful links, too! Thanks!

Comment: Nice solution (+1). The asymptotics can be also obtained directly via the decomposition 
$$e^{i\alpha\big(\sin(wu+\phi)-\sin(wv+\phi)\big)}=1+i\alpha\big(\sin(wu+\phi)-\sin(wv+\phi)\big)-\frac{\alpha^2}{2}\big(\sin(wu+\phi)-\sin(wv+\phi)\big)^2+...$$
The integration is straightforward (over $\phi$ - first). As @Thomas Andrews mentioned, the integral is real, so the next term is only $O(\alpha^4)$